# Limit of a series of the product of two parameterized sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Let $(a_n(\varepsilon)), (b_n(\varepsilon))$ be two sequences of complex numbers depending on a parameter $\varepsilon$ such that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon)$ exists and $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}b_n(\varepsilon)=b$ with $b\neq 0$. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon) b_n(\varepsilon)=b\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon).
\end{equation}

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

Take $a_n(\varepsilon)=\dfrac{1}{2^n}$, and $b_n(\varepsilon)=\dfrac{2^n}{1+(n+1)\varepsilon}- \dfrac{2^n}{1+n\varepsilon}+1$.

Then :

- for every $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, one has $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n(\varepsilon) = 1$, so $\displaystyle \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n(\varepsilon)$ exists.
- for every $n \geq 1$, one has $\displaystyle \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} b_n(\varepsilon) = 1 \neq 0$.
- one has $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon) b_n(\varepsilon) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+(n+1)\varepsilon}- \dfrac{1}{1+n\varepsilon}+\dfrac{1}{2^n} = - \dfrac{1}{1+\varepsilon}+1$$

so we get that $$\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon) b_n(\varepsilon) = 0$$

- but one has also
  $$b\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon) = 1 \times \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^n} = 1$$

so $$\boxed{\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon) b_n(\varepsilon) \neq b\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\varepsilon) }$$